# Dynamically Change Function Used, Based on a Logical Value

Tags: r, function, dynamic

I am trying to figure out how to use a T/F value to use different functions...

Essentially, I am using the `tryCatch` function to produce a bunch of results. I have also created a function titled `myTryCatch` which is essentially the same, but additionally prints out some errors. I would like the user to be able to define whether or not they want to drop the errors, and if so use `tryCatch`, and if not, use `myTryCatch` instead (to print out the specific error received). Is there a way to dynamically change which function is used, without a copy/paste of the entire chunk of code (or even relevant bits)?

I suppose the answer may, indeed, be to find the "relevant bits" and only re-type them? Thoughts?

If there's anything I can clarify, please let me know.

Comment: You can store a function to a variable. Just assign the function you want to use to a variable that you can call either way. It would be easier to help if you provided a core concrete [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of what you are trying to do.

Comment: if I'm understanding this..which is a long shot...look at the documentation on readline() which is an interactive catch at the command line. so if your condition is if (!x){x <-readline ("try a new foo")}